# How to register a new user on XMPP using (a)Smack library

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have set up a xmpp server and android client [using the great post here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)... I have some pre defined users set up in the xmpp server and i could login with those credentials.

Now, from my app i want to register as new users to the xmpp server through the android client. Can anyone please suggest me how to attain this... Any help will be grately appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by developing a webservice that takes the username and password as post parameters. 
If we post the username and pasword, the webservice registers a new user.

Instead of signing up from the app i found this to be rather simple...

Comment: this is not the solution buddy. did you get how to do it in android ?

Answer (score 7):

Smack has InBand registration functionality that can be used via the [AccountManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.1.1/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/iqregister/AccountManager.html) class. Note that not every server has this feature implemented/enabled.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I am late, but if you are using latest `smack-android:4.1.0`, you can try below code for creating `XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration`'s `connection` object and register a user:

```
// Creating a connection
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setHost("myHost.com")  // Name of your Host
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setPort(5222)          // Your Port for accepting c2s connection
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .setServiceName("myServiceName")
                .build();
AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

try {
    // connecting...
    connection.connect();
    Log.i("TAG", "Connected to " + connection.getHost());

    // Registering the user
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
    accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
    accountManager.createAccount(username, password);   // Skipping optional fields like email, first name, last name, etc..
} catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    xmppClient.setConnection(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just elaborating on what [Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7140370/194894) has posted.
`AccountManager` class has all the ingredients for maintaining user accounts in XMPP

Assume you have a connection object created.

```
AccountManager accountManager=new AccountManager(connection);
try {
    accountManager.createAccount("username", "password");
} catch (XMPPException e1) {
    Log.d(e1.getMessage(), e1);
}
```

Comment: this will throw exception and which username password we need to enter ?

Comment: @CoronaPintu what are you trying to do? I didn't get your question.

Comment: i am creating user from applicatoin now same code i had used but it give me exeption in accountManger.createAccount

Comment: 07-15 14:20:29.195: W/System.err(21509): jid-malformed(400)
 07-15 14:20:29.195: W/System.err(21509):   at org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:240)
 07-15 14:20:29.195: W/System.err(21509):   at com.accusol.zipconnect.ui.XMPPClient.createUser(XMPPClient.java:160)
 07-15 14:20:29.195: W/System.err(21509):   at com.accusol.zipconnect.ui.XMPPClient$1.onClick(XMPPClient.java:105)

Comment: @nagprakash hi i am using smack 4.1 and getting accountmanager instance from getinstance method. On checking supportsAccountCreation() on account manager object i am getting, bad-error modify error. what wrong i may be doing?

Answer (score 4):

It's too late but hope it helps

```
           XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                    .builder();
            config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            config.setServiceName("nouman.test");
            config.setHost(serverAddress);
            config.setPort(5222);
            config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
            XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
            config.setSendPresence(true);
            config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            config.setSendPresence(true);
            config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
            connection.connect();


 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("name", "full_name");
        attributes.put("email", "email");
        try {
            if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                accountManager.createAccount("username","password", attributes);
                isAccountCreated = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO : Case 409 or Message conflict is the case of username exist handle the case
            LogUtil.printStackTrace(e);
        }
```

Make sure you have the correct service name otherwise you will get bad request error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used smack 4.1.0 or above version convert your username to Localpart for create new account on server.

```
 public static void registration(String username,ICallBack iCallBack){

    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
    try {
        if(accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()){
            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
            accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(username), username);
            iCallBack.onSuccess();
        }
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException | XMPPException.XMPPErrorException | SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        iCallBack.onFailure(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample.  Minor change need to do is:

    accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(username), username);

to:

<code>accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from(username), password);</code>

Answer (score 0):

I want to update the answer to reflect the change in Asmack library version 4.0 onward. 
Connection.getAccountManager() is now AccountManager.getInstance(XMPPConnection)

```
AccountManager accountManager=AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
try {
    accountManager.createAccount("username", "password");
} catch (XMPPException e1) {
    Log.d(e1.getMessage(), e1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using latest version then use this one.

```
new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(mConnection);
                            accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("username","vinay");
                            map.put("name", "vinay");
                            map.put("password", "vinay");
                            map.put("emial", "vinay@gmail.com");
                            accountManager.createAccount(Localpart.from("vinay"), "vinay", map);
                        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }.start();
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to implement in client [InBand Registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) functionality

Comment: NO need to implement that. Smack comes already with XEP-77 (InBand Registration) support.